# Matrix multiplication not working in C++ armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am using armadillo in C++ and have a very simple issue - can someone please explain to me why I am unable to calculate XtX? I am multiplying a 2x3 and a 3x2 matrix and as soon as I add the last line, the code does not build.

```
mat X(3,2);
X="1 3; 1 2; 1 5";
mat Xt;
Xt=X.t();
mat XtX(2,2);
XtX=Xt*X;
```

This is the error I get:

```
[build] CMakeFiles\MoE.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `void arma::blas::gemv<double>(char const*, int const*, int const*, double const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, double*, int const*)':
    [build] C:/Users/.../include/armadillo_bits/wrapper_blas.hpp:42: undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemv_'
```

Comment: @S.M. the 2x2 refers to the resulting matrix. So, X, is 3x2 X transposed Xt is 2x3, I am multiplying Xt by X so 2x3 by 3x2, which gives me 2x2 (XtX in the code).

Comment: Your are missing some link library on compiler's command line.

Comment: Armadillo can be used as a header-only library, but it requires you to link with some Blas implementation (openblas, mkl, etc) for most of its functionality, such as matrix multiplications, as well as Lapack for other functionality, such as computing SVD. How did you install armadillo?